# regex to match lines not having 11 pipe delimiters

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression in order to find whether we have lines with less or more than 11 pipe deliminators.

I already found the regex for finding lines with exactly 11 deliminators:

```
^([^\|]*\|){11}[^\|]*$
```

I would like to know how to generate the negative regex of this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a negative lookahead with this regex.

Comment: You can use: `^(?!(?:[^|]*\|){11}[^|]*$)`

Comment: What regex language? What programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
^(?:(?:[^\|]*\|[^\|]*){0,10}|(?:[^\|]*\|[^\|]*){12,})$
```